# TypeError: notes.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react and I try to get an array of data from the backend and display it in the component. This is the code I wrote for that.

```
const [notes, getNotes] = useState('');

    useEffect(()=>{
        getAllNotes();
    }, []);

    const getAllNotes = async () => {
        await axios.get(`/buyerPosts`)
            .then ((response)=>{
                const allNotes=response.data.existingPosts;
                getNotes(allNotes);
               }
            )
            .catch(error=>console.error(`Error: ${error}`)
        );
    }
    console.log(notes);
```

The map function is this:

```
{notes.map((notes,index)=>(
        <article>
            <div className="text-b">
              <h3>Post ID: {index+1}</h3>
                 <p>Location: {notes.address}
                 </p>
            </div>
        </article>
      )
   )
}
```

But then I get an error like this:
TypeError: notes.map is not a function

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: are you getting data from api ? have to checked ?

Comment: change useState(''); to useState([]). This ensures your map won't break. Also change [] in iseEffect to [notes] to ensure it reloads when this value changes

Comment: change `const [notes, getNotes] = useState('')` to `const [notes, getNotes] = useState([])`

Comment: @AmruthLS Yes, I'm getting data from a rest API and it is working correctly and I use this `console.log(notes);` to check data is coming. An array prints in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set initial values to empty array.

```
const [notes, getNotes] = useState([]);
```

make sure your type is array before updating. also for safer side do null checks.

```
{notes?.map((notes,index)=>(
        <article>
            <div className="text-b">
              <h3>Post ID: {index+1}</h3>
                 <p>Location: {notes.address}
                 </p>
            </div>
        </article>
      )
   )
}
```

Comment: thanks so much. This works for me. What is the difference between `useState('')` and `useState([])`?

Comment: useState takes argument it is to set initial value. if you set notes value to `''` then notes value type is string so you can't use `map` with string value. if you set to `[]` then you can use map or any other array methods since type is array